# Inject additional data in a method

Tags: c++, code-injection

I am adding the new module in some large library. All methods here are implemented as static. Let me briefly describe the simplified model:

```
typedef std::vector<double> TData;
double test ( const TData &arg ) { return arg ( 0 ) * sin ( arg ( 1 ) + ...;}
double ( * p_test ) ( const TData> &arg) = &test;

class A
{
    public:
      static T f1 (TData &input) {
         .... //some computations
         B::f2 (p_test);
      }
};
```

Inside `f1()` some computations are performed and a static method `B::f2` is called. The `f2` method is implemented by another author and represents some simulation algorithm (example here is simplified).

```
class B
{
    public:
      static double f2 (double ( * p_test ) ( const TData  &arg ) )
      {
          //difficult algorithm working p_test many times
          double res = p_test(arg);
      }
};
```

The `f2` method has a pointer to some weight function (here `p_test`). But in my case some additional parameters computed in `f1` for `test()` methods are required

```
 double test ( const TData &arg, const TData &arg2, char *arg3.... ) { }
```

How to inject these parameters into `test()` (and so to `f2`) to avoid changing the source code of the `f2` methods (that is not trivial), redesign of the library and without dirty hacks :-) ?

The most simple step is to override `f2`

```
static double f2 (double ( * p_test ) ( const TData  &arg ), const TData &arg2, char *arg3....  )
```

But what to do later? Consider, that methods are static, so there will be problems with objects.

---

**Updated question**

Is it possible to make a pointer to a function dependent on some template parameter or do something like that

```
if (condition) res = p_test(arg);
else res = p_test2(arg, arg2, arg3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without dirty hacks

Not gonna happen. If you can't modify the source of a function taking a function pointer, you'll have to use an exception vomit to gain the extra arguments. If you had a C++11 compiler (that does not exist yet) which supports `thread_local`, it's theoretically possible to do something better, or you could use OS-specific TLS. But as of right now, the only portable solution is an exception vomit.

```
void f(void(*fp)()) { fp(); }
void mah_func() { 
    try { 
        throw; 
    } catch(my_class* m) {
        m->func();
    }
}
int main() {
    my_class m;
    try {
        throw &m;
    } catch(my_class* p) {
        f(mah_func);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, in your scenario, modifying `f2` doesn't seem to be impossible, only difficult. However, the difficulty of altering it to take a `std::function<double(const TData&)>` would be very low- all you'd have to do is change the argument type, thanks to operator overloading. It should be a very simple change for even a complex function, as you're only changing the type of the function parameter, all the call sites will still work, etc. Then you can pass a proper function object made through `bind` or a lambda or somesuch.

Comment: if the compiler supports thread-safe exceptions, then likely it's also supported by e.g. Boost threads. so, cleaner to use thread local storage directly. if the compiler doesn't support thread safe exceptions (and nothing in C++03 standard supported threading), then this technique, although technically interesting, is *not portable*.

Answer (score 1):

"avoid changing", well that's a bit difficult.

however, you can use a static variable to pass arguments across calls of functions that don't pass the arguments.

remember that if there is more than one thread using those function, you need to either use thread local storage (which is what i recommend for that) or else ensure proper mutual exclusion for use of those variables, where in the case of a single variable shared between all the threads means exclusion all the way down the call chain. but do use thread local storage if threading is a problem. and if no threading problem, well, no problem! :-)